# How to end song at `fine` but after repeating?

Tags: notation, repeats

I'm transcribing guitar song to tab but facing a problem. As the song has repetitions I wrote tab like this and expect to go like `1 2 1 2 3 4 3 4 1 2 1 2` but actually it is  `1 2 1 2 3 4 3 4 1 2`; song stops at `fine` without repeating. How can I end song at `fine` after repeating?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to get some software to behave properly?  If so, please let us know what software it is.

Comment: Repeats are normally skipped after a D.C. But both times, “1 2” gets played. I recommend just writing those 4 measures out.

Answer (score 9):

All you have to do is change the “ DC al fine” to “DC al fine (with repeat)” to be clear of your intentions.

One issue you might encounter is that in bar 4 a DC in a bar with a repeat sign may potentially cause confusion. An easy solution is to add a bar 5 and have bars 4 and 5 be 1st and 2nd endings with the DC on bar 5. That way the potential confusion from the combination of the repeat sign and DC will be eliminated.

In the modern age of digital notation and the ease of copy/pasting it is sometimes better to write something out using more measures and maybe an extra page and try and cut down on excess repeats and road map instructions. It will yield better results when players are sight reading your charts.

Comment: I do not see much of a problem having a D.C. at the end of a repeated section. That is something that happens quite commonly in Trios and such. But your remark about writing it out is really important: Jump marks can cause high amounts of confusion, especially if they are used in such abundance as done in pop music. But on the other hand jump marks can make the score shorter and easier to handle. So it’s generally a question of a good eye for aesthetics and clarity.

Comment: @Lazy I’m not saying it’s wrong to put a jump mark at the end of a repeated section, just that it’s better not to. People often react to the first thing they see and that can cause someone to skip the repeat. I agree that jump marks are useful if used with a good eye like you say but there are a lot of bad eyes out there! ;)

Comment: I’m not an expert, but I’ve seen a D.C. at a repeated section many times (e.g. Beethoven Sonata 14.II). I do not know how it is in pop and jazz where such jump marks are used for a lot (which also leads to many cases that are incredibly hard to follow and thus impossible to sightread). I guess this is again something that might be fine in one case and confusing in another one. I’ve seen jump marks that jump onto a different page for a single measure just to jump back after that one single measure...

Comment: @Lazy After so many years I’ve seem all those things too Lazy, that’s why I try and avoid anything that is vague in the least and recommend others do so as well. I’ve noticed that the biggest time wasters in rehearsals and cause of mistakes in performances seem to be charts with road maps.

Comment: That is a very wise remark ...

Answer (score 0):

By writing that instruction in the score.   For a live player, you mark it (something like) 'Make repeat after D.C.'

I think this is worth doing, for absolute clarity, even if the coda jump is in a 2X volta section.   The old convention of 'no repeats after a DC' dies hard.

For how to achieve this playback in your particular notation program, you'll have to consult its manual.